# Using docker-compose, how do I share my image to docker-hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm very new to docker, I made a simple django app with docker-compose.

How do I post it to docker hub so someone can run `docker run` against it?

Answer (score 8):

Docker hub is a repository for Docker images (make with a Dockerfile).  When you use docker-compose your are simply connecting together one or more images on docker hub using your composition (the yaml that describes the images and how to connect them). You aren't making an Image with docker-compose. I don't think there is a place to store/share compositions (yet) at Docker.  However, you might take a look at tutum.co.  There you can save your docker-compose (they call them stacks) and deploy them from tutum. Full disclosure, I have nothing to do with tutum.co.

Comment: Well, looks like you were right.. Tutum was bought by Docker just a few days ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

As the last answer said, Docker hub is only for Docker images (i.e. dockerfiles).
Tutum was bought by docker and recently shut down:

> Tutum has shut down as of May 31st 2016. An evolution of the service
>   is now offered in Docker Cloud

It looks like there is an attempt (end of 2015) to create a kind of hub for docker-compose.yml files, using github: [composehub.com](https://composehub.com/)

It doesn't seem very dynamic ( 55 stars on [github](https://github.com/composehub/cli), last update a year ago, on October 2015)